# PHP returns whitespace character before anything after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, whitespace

I am using `XMLHttpRequest` to get some data from my server. I use the first letter as a flag for error or success. This was working fine but after a point while not changing anything on server or php configuration, the request started to return white space first character. I dealed with it by trimming it, but I am wondering how this could happen. If anybody can help I would really appreciate it. I can give some money also for deeper investigations. In my PHP file that is called from javascript. I use const value for true or false flag which is 0 and 1. Something goes wrong and before this const variable a whitespace is being echoed.Is it php echoing it or javascript changed behaviour and is adding whitespace in `XMLHttpRequest` response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either track down where the whitespace is coming from or call phps `ob_clean`

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php)

> This function discards the contents of the output buffer.
>
> This function does not destroy the output buffer like ob_end_clean()
>   does.
>
> The output buffer must be started by ob_start() with
>   PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE flag. Otherwise ob_clean() will not work.

Comment: What is the difference if i store everything in a variable and at the end echo the variable? That is what i do. I do sprintf everything into a variable and then echoing it. I think i ll disable output_buffering from php.ini file. What is your opinion?

Comment: You have some white space output by php. If you eradicate this then you can call echo and then exit to ensure only the JSON is output. A work around would be to clear the buffer. You could walk through your code with an exit, checking the output until you find where the white space is being output. Hope that helps

Comment: So after using ob_clean() at the start of my code,before echoing anything,  the white spaces are removed. One thing i don't understand is that why is it working since i don't use ob_start() anywhere. PHP manual states this. The output buffer must be started by ob_start() with PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE flag. Otherwise ob_clean() will not work. Anyway i tried disabling output_buffering and i ran on issues with headers already sent. Can somebody provide me with a deeper explanation of this buffering and header issues?  This functionality should be more obvious in PHP manual.

Comment: Glad it works. The ob contains anything output by `php`. `ob_start()` function works by catching all output to buffer and then implicitly output this buffer on script end. It will still be sent to the `ob` without start set. But PHP will determine when to send the buffer. Please mark answer as accepted if resolved your issue

Comment: OK, its the tick at the left.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before i was using laravel and it was just the cache i cleared the cache with php artisan cache:clear and it worked so maybe it's the same for you